Unable to add the web service in the exiting solution using VS 2019
I want to add new web service in existing solution but not getting option to add.
Also in the property of the solution the framework dropdown is disabled.
I am using VS 2019.
I have tried making changes in the csproj file changing the target framework.
When I ma trying to do in another solution I am able to add the web reference using connected service and service reference option
Thanks in Advance.

Property Screen.

Add reference screen.

Depending on your question tag you want to add Services. The picture in the title is Assembly.  What I understand by adding a service is right-click on the project-add-service reference.
